# How to change the image in the upper left corner in a java program

Tags: java, image, swing

I want to know that how to change the image in the upper left corner in a java program and in the taskbar.
See the screenshot to know what i am talking about-
http://www.ougfiles.com/dl/303275944/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setIconImage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) or [`setIconImages()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29). The latter lets you specify a list of icons in different resolutions; the most suitable one will be used in each case (desktop, taskbar, title bar of the frame, etc.)

See also the [this section](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated) in the Java tutorial.

Comment: I tried this earlier but its not happening for me

Comment: @Vipul: I suggest to try one of the examples from the Tutorial I linked. Otherwise you can try to reduce your code to a short, self-contained example (http://sscce.org) and add it to your question so that we can have a look.

Comment: thanks got it to work after invoking the setdecoratedannfeel method and using the object of the frame :))

Comment: Then you might consider to upvote and/or accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`Window.setIconImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29), where the "window" will probably be a `JFrame` if this is a Swing app.

Note that there's also [`Window.setIconImages`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29) which allows you to set *multiple* images, so that it can pick up different resolutions for different situations (e.g. a bigger icon in the Windows task bar than in the frame itself.)

Comment: thanks got it to work after invoking the setdecoratedannfeel method :))

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google searched revealed a setIconImage for your Frame
[frame.setIconImage() (oracle.com)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29)